# How to properly install SoapySDR with LimeSDR USB

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I want to write a C code using SoapySDR to control my LimeSDR USB. But, it seems like SoapySDR is not installed, yet it should be included during the installation of the drivers.

So, first of all, the installed the drivers of the LimeSDR Hardware using the steps in the wiki as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:myriadrf/drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install limesuite liblimesuite-dev limesuite-udev limesuite-images
sudo apt-get install soapysdr-tools soapysdr-module-lms7

#soapysdr-tools use to be called just soapysdr on older packages
sudo apt-get install soapysdr soapysdr-module-lms7
```

Then I tested the following commands:

```
$ SoapySDRUtil --info
######################################################
##     Soapy SDR -- the SDR abstraction library     ##
######################################################

Lib Version: v0.7.1-myriadrf1~ubuntu18.04
API Version: v0.7.1
ABI Version: v0.7
Install root: /usr
Search path:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/SoapySDR/modules0.7
Search path:  /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/SoapySDR/modules0.7   (missing)
Search path:  /usr/local/lib/SoapySDR/modules0.7                    (missing)
Module found: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/SoapySDR/modules0.7/libLMS7Support.so (19.01.0)   
Available factories... lime
Available converters...
-  CF32 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8, CU16, CU8]
-  CS16 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8, CU16, CU8]
-  CS32 -> [CS32]
-   CS8 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8, CU16, CU8]
-  CU16 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8]
-   CU8 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8]
-   F32 -> [F32, S16, S8, U16, U8]
-   S16 -> [F32, S16, S8, U16, U8]
-   S32 -> [S32]
-    S8 -> [F32, S16, S8, U16, U8]
-   U16 -> [F32, S16, S8]
-    U8 -> [F32, S16, S8]
```

when I tried to run a simple code :

```
  #include <SoapySDR/Device.h>
  #include <SoapySDR/Formats.h>
  #include <stdio.h> //printf
  #include <stdlib.h> //free
  #include <complex.h>

  int main(void)
  {
     size_t length;

     //enumerate devices
     SoapySDRKwargs *results = SoapySDRDevice_enumerate(NULL, &length);
     for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
       printf("Found device #%d: ", (int)i);
       for (size_t j = 0; j < results[i].size; j++)
       {
          printf("%s=%s, ", results[i].keys[j], results[i].vals[j]);
       }
       printf("\n");

    printf("Done\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```

I compiled as following

```
  gcc -std=c99 API_example.c -lSoapySDR && ./a.out
```

I got the following error:

```
  API_example.c:1:10: fatal error: SoapySDR/Device.h: No such file or directory
  #include <SoapySDR/Device.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Anyone have an idea about how to fix it?

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:myriadrf/drivers` gettubg error `ppa myraidrf/drivers not found`

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue just a few minutes ago. Follow this guide exactly and it should work. https://github.com/pothosware/SoapySDR/wiki/BuildGuide#ubuntu

I am assuming you are running a debian distro, but if not the guide will also have you covered.

sudo apt-get install cmake g++

sudo apt-get install libpython-dev python-numpy swig

git clone https://github.com/pothosware/SoapySDR.git

cd SoapySDR

mkdir build

cd build

cmake ..

make -j4

sudo make install

sudo ldconfig #needed on debian systems

SoapySDRUtil --info

Now you should be able to compile. I had the same issue as you even when I thought I had it installed. Give this a run and it should set you up.